# Terraform and OCI : "The existing Db System with ID <OCID> has a conflicting state of UPDATING" when creating multiple databases

Tags: oracle, terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create 30 databases (oci_database_database resource) under 5 existing db_homes. All of these resources are under a single DB System :

When applying my code, a first database is successfully created then when terraform attempts to create the second one I get the following error message : "Error: Service error:IncorrectState. The existing Db System with ID has a conflicting state of UPDATING", which causes the execution to stop.

If I re-apply my code, the second database is created then I get the same previous error when terraform attempts to create the third one.

I am assuming I get this message because terraform starts creating the following database as soon as the first one is created, but the DB System status is not up to date yet (still 'UPDATING' instead of 'AVAILABLE').

A good way for the OCI provider to avoid this issue would be to consider a database creation as completed when the creation is indeed completed AND the associated db home and db system's status are back to 'AVAILABLE'.

Any suggestion on how to adress the issue I am encountering ?

Feel free to ask if you need any additional information.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `terraform apply -parallelism=1`?
[Terraform docs on parallel execution.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#parallelism-n)

Comment: Looks like you [have](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-oci/issues/1185).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it looks like you have opened a ticket regarding this via [github](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-oci/issues/1185). What you are experiencing should not happen, as terraform should retry after seeing the error. As per your github post, the person helping you is in need of your log with timestamp so they can better troubleshoot. At this stage I would recommend following up there and sharing the requested info.